# Nativescript Orientation/AutoRotate Issues

Tags: ios, angular, nativescript

I am getting a few warnings when running an IOS build with NativeScript. 
The main issue is that changes in orientation are not being handled correctly. When rotating the phone, I can see that the orientation change event is registering and correctly recognizes the new orientation but the view does not adjust.

My guess is that this behavior is related to the warnings generated below.

I have gone through the latest update process and should be up to date on everything. I have not been able to find any issues related to these warnings and NativeScript anywhere. Does anyone know anything about how to solve this issue.

`[19-03-14 10:27:30.059] (CLI) 3 warnings generated.

[19-03-14 10:27:30.833] (CLI) ****/platforms/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController.m:458:1: warning: implementing deprecated method [-Wdeprecated-implementations]

[19-03-14 10:27:30.833] (CLI) - (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

[19-03-14 10:27:30.833] (CLI) ^
[19-03-14 10:27:30.833] (CLI) In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/benjaminb/Desktop/projects/HelloWorld/platforms/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController-prefix.pch:2:
[19-03-14 10:27:30.833] (CLI)

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIViewController.h:328:1: note: method 'willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:' declared here

[19-03-14 10:27:30.833] (CLI) - (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0,8_0, "Implement viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: instead") __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
[19-03-14 10:27:30.833] (CLI) ^
[19-03-14 10:27:30.833] (CLI) ***/platforms/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController.m:490:1: warning: implementing deprecated method [-Wdeprecated-implementations]

[19-03-14 10:27:30.833] (CLI) - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

[19-03-14 10:27:30.833] (CLI) ^
[19-03-14 10:27:30.833] (CLI) In module 'UIKit' imported from ****/platforms/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController-prefix.pch:2:
[19-03-14 10:27:30.833] (CLI)

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIViewController.h:331:1: note: method 'willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:' declared here

[19-03-14 10:27:30.833] (CLI) - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(3_0,8_0, "Implement viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: instead") __TVOS_PROHIBITED;

[19-03-14 10:27:30.833] (CLI) ^
[19-03-14 10:27:30.833] (CLI) ****/platforms/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController.m:515:1: warning: implementing deprecated method [-Wdeprecated-implementations]

[19-03-14 10:27:30.833] (CLI) - (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
[19-03-14 10:27:30.833] (CLI) ^
[19-03-14 10:27:30.833] (CLI) In module 'UIKit' imported from ***/platforms/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController-prefix.pch:2:

[19-03-14 10:27:30.833] (CLI) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIViewController.h:329:1: note: method 'didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:' declared here

[19-03-14 10:27:30.833] (CLI) - (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0,8_0) __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
[19-03-14 10:27:30.833] (CLI) ^`

Comment: I think this must be discussed in the [plugin repo](https://github.com/bthurlow/nativescript-imagecropper/issues) Or the [native library's repo](https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController/issues).

Comment: I have submitted an issue with the repo as well.